# Method return Type cannot use *this*

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, type-hinting, vue-cli, vue3-sfc-loader

I'm currently being assigned a task where I have to test out Vue as a frontend framework, another developer is testing out React.

The main takeaway is we want strong type hinting and errors on compile, I'm struggling to implement a method return type.

**Works:**

```
<template>
  <div class="home flex flex-col">
    <h1 class="flex justify-center">Spy Table:</h1>
    <h2>Hi: {{ test2() }}</h2>
    <SpyTable />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import SpyTable from "@/components/SpyTable/SpyTable.vue";

function test3(): string {
  return "Vue Test 3";
}

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    dataset: {
      type: Object as () => FormType,
      required: true,
    },
    name: String,
    msg: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  methods: {
    test1: function (): string {
      return "Vue Test 1";
    },
    test2: function (): typeof test3 {
      return test3;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

The above example will work, the method test2 is hinted to return a `typeof` test3 function, this works all fine.

Does not work:

```
<template>
  <div class="home flex flex-col">
    <h1 class="flex justify-center">Spy Table:</h1>
    <h2>Hi: {{ test2() }}</h2>
    <SpyTable />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import SpyTable from "@/components/SpyTable/SpyTable.vue";

function test3(): string {
  return "Vue Test 3";
}

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    dataset: {
      type: Object as () => FormType,
      required: true,
    },
    name: String,
    msg: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  methods: {
    test1: function (): string {
      return "Vue Test 1";
    },
    test2: function (): typeof this.test1 {
      return this.test1;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

This will not work, it won't compile and in general, just gives me trouble... Is there not a way for me to tell `test2` that it should expect a `typeof` test1 to be returned?

I really would like to be able to do this as I am working with Vue on my own private project, I really like Vue, and there is another colleague who is doing the same as I am just with react, I would really like that the company chooses vue, can someone help me out solving this?

Comment: When hovering the broken sample it tells me this:  Property 'test1' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstanc

Comment: I'm looking into Composition API, is this the only way to solve this current problem?

Comment: In `test2: function (): typeof this.test1 {`, `this` refers to the outer context (likely `window`), not the component instance. It's not possible to get `this` as the component when declaring methods with the Options API because the component instance doesn't yet exist. You'd either have to stick with the first solution you verified (using external functions), or switch to the Composition API.